# UFW how to block traffic from IP:Port 8X.19X.1X.1XX:5065 to any:5060

Tags: ip, ufw

I've read a lot about UFW rules. But I can't find a combination to block traffic from IP1:port1 to IP2:port2.

Voila le log

time   protocol src_ip src_port dest_ip dest_port
Fri Sep 15 05:21:59 2023 UDP 8X.19X.1X.1XX 5065  => 9.87.179.94 5060

Can anyone help me?

I've looked into it but I haven't seen a really accurate case.